# How to group/aggregate rows in a table based on values in a column

Tags: sql, aggregate, amazon-redshift

I have a table of chats between buyers and sellers, and in many cases there are chats between the same buyer and a seller (with different chatids), that have different lastactivity dates (shown here in Unix time).

[image: The table as it currently looks]

My goal is to be able to query this table so that only a single chatid is returned for each buyer/seller pair, and this chatid corresponds to whichever chat had the most recent lastactivity - so like this:

[image: The goal for the table]

I've tried:

```
SELECT max(lastactivity), chatid, buyerid, supplierid, 
FROM chat_table 
GROUP BY 2,3,4
```

but this doesn't seem to work...
Anyone able to help?

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: [You should not post code or sample data as an image because...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451)

Comment: I've tried:

SELECT 
max(lastactivity),
chatid,
buyerid,
supplierid,
FROM chat_table
GROUP BY 2,3,4

but this doesn't seem to work... the result is identical to the starting table

Comment: This is because your chatids are at least somewhat unique.  This would work if you remove chatid from select and group by.  Do you need chatid?

Comment: yes - absolutely need to keep chatids in the final table

Comment: so do the select with group by without the chatid in a subquery and then join back to the same table based on lastactivity, buyer, and seller to recover chatid

Comment: From the images you posted, from the four (4) interactions between _John Doe_ and _Dairy Co_, you want the one with `chatid` equal to `5787560e-b269-4aab-9d98-cafe32333b71`. Pardon my ignorance, but I don't see the criteria or logic used to determine that. Can you explain?

Comment: @alexherm would it not be the opposite direction (ie join back chatid in a subquery)?

Comment: @Abra the `chatid` for the most recent activity should be returned - ie where the `lastactivity` value is largest

Comment: @KUpadhyay  if my answer helped you, it'll be great if you could also upvote it. Cheers !

Comment: @KUpadhyay - which solution worked the best?

Comment: @alexherm all of them seemed to do the job, I ended up going with Yankee's as it made most sense intuitively to me, but thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simpler approach, using self-JOIN,

```
SELECT a.buyerid, a.sellerid, a.chatid, a.lastactivity 
FROM chat_table a 
JOIN (SELECT MAX(lastactivity),buyerid, sellerid FROM chat_table GROUP BY buyerid, sellerid) b
ON a.buyerid = b.buyerid
AND a.sellerid = b.sellerid
AND a.lastactivity = b.lastactivity ;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Redshift, I would do use window functions:

```
select ct.*
from (select ct.*,
             row_number() over (partition by least(buyerid, supplierid), greatest(buyerid, supplierid)
                                order by lastactivity
                               ) as seqnum
      from chat_table ct
     ) ct
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.lastactivity, a.buyerid, a.supplierid, a.chatid
from (SELECT max(lastactivity) lastactivity, buyerid, supplierid 
    FROM chat_table 
    GROUP BY 2,3) a
left join chat_table b on a.buyerid=b.buyerid and a.supplierid=b.supplierid and a.lastactivity=b.kastactivity;
```

Answer (score 1):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM chat_table c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM chat_table
  WHERE buyerid = c.buyerid AND supplierid = c.supplierid AND lastactivity > c.lastactivity
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use window function like row_number. 
The partition will be the buyer_id and seller_id, 
order by the lastactivity.

In the outer query filter the rows where rownumber=1.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html

Answer (score 1):

As this question is tagged to aws-redshift. Below query works. Try this.

Select *from chat_table
where (buyerid,sellerid, lastactivity)
IN(
Select buyerid,sellerid, max(lastactivity) as lastactivity
from chat_table
Group by buyerid,sellerid);